# Intuitive $O(n\, \text{log}(n))$ example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

I'm having a hard time getting the intuition of an algorithm with worst-case complexity $O(n\,\text{log}(n))$. Is any informative example available?

Comment: Take a look at this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this lecture where it explains merge sort. I believe the relevant section is around 27 minutes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LOwPhPDwVc